# android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be casted to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have a scenario in which I'm supposed to inject a Class into my recyclerview. In order to inject my dagger class I need to get hold of context .so I wrote the following code in my recyclerview class

```
 Components.<DepComponent>getFrom(parent.getContext()).inject(this);
```

Inside the`DepComponent` I have an inject method in which this particular recycler view is also added

When I run the code I am getting this error

`android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to target.dagger.HasComponent`

I have tried to cast `(Activity)parent.getContext()` but the following error is being thrown

`android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to Activity`

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Looks like parent.getContext() is returning `ContextThemeWrapper` which is not being casted to an activity

Comment: What specifically does `getFrom` take as a paramter?

Comment: Activity or FragmentActivity

Comment: `ContextThemeWrapper` is a wrapper you need to get the wrapped context using `getBaseContext` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext()

Comment: you mean `parent.getContext().getBaseContext()`?. if that is the case ,there is method like``getBaseContext()` against `parent.getContext()`

Comment: See my answer on how this can be done.

Comment: In your layout xml, in your `<RecyclerView>` tag, are you using the `android:theme` attribute?

Comment: No , `android:theme` is not used

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following method to get an activity from a context or throw and exception if it is a non Activity based context:

```
private fun getActivity(context: Context): Activity {
    return when (context) {
        is Activity -> context
        is ContextWrapper -> getActivity(context.getBaseContext())
        else -> error("Non Activity based context")
    }
}
```

Like so:

`Components.<DepComponent>getFrom(getActivity(context)).inject(this);`

Comment: `getBaseContext()` would work only if the context is set by the constructor or `setBaseContext`.which is not happening in my case

Comment: How are you getting your context? I need to see more code to be able to help.